# Update ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: updates, update-manager, update-alternatives

I am currently using ubuntu 15.04, but I want to update this version to the latest ubuntu version i.e 15.10.I have changed the settings as required, but I am not able to find update manager in the search box.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to run Software Updater, allow it to update the system. After that it should prompt you to restart and after the reboot, check Software Updater again. This dialog should be displayed.

[image: Ubuntu 15.10 Update Image].

If you don't get a new upgrade information, open "Software & Updates" and click on the updates tab. Change the option on "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "For any new version".

[image]

After this, just follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Switch on` your computer.

`Press` and `hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your computer will begin the boot process.

Your workstation should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Enable networking`. Press `Return` with this option `highlighted`.

Other of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press `Return` with this option `highlighted`.

Your computer boot to the hard disk in a terminal, type the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
do-release-upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```